# Java - JFileChooser Images

Tags: java, swing, icons, jfilechooser

This may seem like a stupid question, but I need to know where the images used for JFileChooser are located. By images, I mean the image of a file or folder next to the file name.

Here is a picture if you don't understand.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxX9Q.png

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileSystemView.getSystemIcon(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon%28java.io.File%29)

See [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) for example code.

[image]

Comment: @GagandeepBali  Wish I had a dollar for every single thing I *didn't* know about Swing.  I could have a great weekend getaway, or perhaps a week in one of the less expensive tourist destinations.  ;)